# Adding one table to another with one common (but shuffled) column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 tables with a common column (named project_name). The order of project_name in table2 is different than the order in table1 (for reference check the screenshots).
How could I combine both tables (either in excel or in python as dataframes)?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could easily use a `Table.Join` in `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

Answer (score 1):

Using Excel, I would use INDEX/MATCH as below:

[image]

```
=INDEX(B$12:B$14,MATCH($A3,$A$12:$A$14,0))
```

Please see https://exceljet.net/index-and-match for a full explanation of INDEX/MATCH.

The #N/A mean that the project name did not appear in table 2, and can be replaced with any desired value by wrapping the formula in a IFNA:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(B$12:B$14,MATCH($A3,$A$12:$A$14,0)),<Value if not found>)
```

The MATCH returns the index of the current project name in table 2. The INDEX then uses that to return the desired data.

Once that is done, you can copy and paste as values to remove the formulae if desired.